# Make an input field mask with dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder=".........">
```

When a user enters the field with some text I would like the dots to be replaced with the letters. So if I entered "Ha" in it. The user sees this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ha.......">
```

And so on for the other letters

I've seen a lot of examples with dates, numbers and ip's but am still quite not sure on how to reproduce this to my problem.

Comment: Does the expected length of the input match the number of dots?

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: I've ad to do this for projects and remember it being really painful. (Especially when you start accounting for mobile devices)

Comment: here are some plugins : http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-mask-input-plugin/

Comment: @Halcyon: No there is no expected number to match. So it has to be an amount of dots of my choosing.

Comment: @wapsee: It would be really great if we could get this to work on mobile devices too. Thanks for the plugins.

Comment: @j08691: I'll post some code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this would be slightly complicated.

First, create a new duplicated input which will act as the "placeholder" as it will float behind the real input field. Then attach event listener on the real input and fill the value into the "placeholder".

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 24px;">
        <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 1; color: #ccc" id="placeholder">
        <input type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 2; background-color: transparent; color: #000" id="realInput">
    </div>
    <script>
      function fillPlaceholder(){
        //suppose you want 9 characters for the placeholder
        var limit = 9;
        var text = $("#realInput").val();
        while (text.length < limit) {
            text += ".";
        }
        $("#placeholder").val(text);
      }
      $("#realInput").on("input", fillPlaceholder);
      fillPlaceholder();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really thanks for such a short and simple answer. Never thought about it this way.